Remove an optional prop from an object by destructuring
What I need to to define noAge as being Person right in the destructure line. As you see I'd like to assign age to noAge later:
interface Person{
    name: string
    age?: number
}

const person: Person = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: 20
};

const {age, ...noAge} = person;

noAge.age = 30; // an error here

It shows the type of noAge being:
const noAge: {
    name: string;
}

but I want it to be Person.
Everything I tried so far was an error.
Playground

That is the type of noAge. Wanting Person seems like an unreasonable expectation; it's already compatible with Person. Why does the name of the type matter?

@jonrsharpe try to assign age to noAge.  i need that later

Please [edit] to provide relevant context and give a [mre] of an actual problem.

@jonrsharpe added the age assignment for your pleasure

I have to agree with @jonrsharpe here — the expectation doesn't seem reasonable. Is the goal to create a copy of the person object — without the age property — and maintain the type? If so, you can do it like this: const noAge = structuredClone(person); delete noAge.age;. If that answers your question, I can write it as one (or find a duplicate target for this question). If not, what did I miss?

This is not the way deconstructing is working. Write a function doing this for you and set the property to undefined or delete the property. This should keep the type.

@jsejcksn yes, exactly i don't want to use delete here and i want to figure how to use destructuring with types

@ThomasRenger i want to learn typescript syntax how to do that with destructuring, the answer either typescript have a syntax for my case or not

^ @AlexanderNenashev I think you might have a misconception about destructuring assignments — the purpose is to de-structure an object — in other words: break it apart into separate units — this includes the associated type information. The delete operator exists for a reason and is the idiomatic approach in this scenario.

@jsejcksn nope, it's not idiomatic, by destructuring you simultaneously create a shallow copy and delete a prop

I guess you want a function like this — along the lines of what @ThomasRenger suggested?

^ "Deleting a prop" by assigning its value to a variable in a destructuring assignment no longer qualifies the remaining portion of the destructured object as a copy (the portion which is assigned to another variable using spread/rest syntax).

@jsejcksn the rest portion is a shallow copy without destuctured props. if you think otherwise please provide a corresponding code to showcase

I don't think there's a way to provide a type annotation for the rest property in a variable declaration using destructuring patterns - at least none for a type including the other properties. The best solution I can suggest is to declare the variables up front, then assign them:
let age: number | undefined, noAge: Person;
({age, ...noAge} = person);

noAge.age = 30;

or just introduce an extra variable:
const {age, ...noAge} = person;
const oldPerson: Person = noAge;
oldPerson.age = 30;


Of course, the idiomatic solution would be to just not use destructuring at all if you want to put a new age back on the noAge object, but use an object literal with spread syntax:
const {age} = person;
const oldPerson = {...person, age: 30};


i want to add age conditionally and used your first suggestion in the first place. anyway thanks for clarifying that's the only way
